# Find sibling using XPath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to find sibling element text using xpath

```html
<label>
<span>some span</span>  
</label>
<label>
    Second Label
</label>
```

```
//label[normalize-space(text()) = 'some span']/following-sibling::label/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python we would do something like this :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[//text()[normalize-space() = 'some span']]/following-sibling::label").text
```

basically Python Selenium bindings provide a `text` method for web element. `getText()` for Java.

Now if you want to heavily dependent on XPATH then you can try below XPATH :

```
//span[contains(text(),'some span')]/../following-sibling::label
```

or probably

```
//span[contains(text(),'some span')]/../following-sibling::label[contains(text(),'Second Label')]
```

Comment: Looks good except that you ought to switch one of those sets of single quotes out for double quotes

Comment: @C.Peck : Well you can use something like this also `//label[//text()[normalize-space() = 'some span']]`

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
//label[span[text()='some span']]/following-sibling::label/text()
```

or if you only want to find that if it is actually the first following-element:(i.e: you don't want to find that label if there is a input in between)

```
//label[span[text()='some span']]/following-sibling::*[1][self::label]/text()
```

or if you only want to find that the first following label(if there even more following label-elements):

```
//label[span[text()='some span']]/following-sibling::label[1]/text()
```

Comment: you should avoid numeric represent while writing locators.

Comment: @cruisepandey: that depends completely on your usecase. In the usecases I describe this is how you do should that using XPath

Comment: that is one the bad practice. Cause when you write div[1] and if UI developer introduce one more div in the same container your Xpath will fail. You will never have robust framework if you use numerical representation.

Comment: right now it is first following-element, it's true but we have better options for that don't we ?

Comment: @cruisepandey: The first XPath is the best XPath to OP-question. I will explain the alternatives better.